How do I write this sql statement in SQLAlchemy with FastAPI
I am trying to convert a program I wrote in Python to FastAPI / SQLAlchemy. I don't know if I should find a way to use the SQL I already have (see below) or to try and use SQLALchemy filtering.  I tried using a filter:
Schema:
class Flights(Base):
    __tablename__ = "flights"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    timestamp = Column(TIMESTAMP)
    flight = Column(String)
    dept_city = Column(String)
    arr_city = Column(String)
    dept_utc = Column(String)
    arr_utc = Column(String)

now = datetime.now()

flight = db.query(Flights)

flight = flight.filter(datetime(Flights.arr_utc, '-30 minutes') >= now,
   Flights.dept_utc <= now,
   Flights.act_in == 'None' or Flights.act_in == Null,
   Flights.invalid=='')

..however I get an error for the datetime 30 minute time shift conversion on the arr_utc field. Also the OR doesn't seem to work either. I'm sorta new to SQLAlchemy.
Here is my original SQL statement that works fine before I switched to using FastAPI, SqlAlchemy:
    dte = datetime.now()

    c.execute("SELECT * from flights) WHERE ? \
    BETWEEN datetime(dept_utc,'-30 minutes') AND datetime(arr_utc,'+30 minutes') \
    AND ((act_in = 'None') OR (act_in is null)) \
    AND (invalid is NULL) \
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC \
    LIMIT 1;", [dte])

Thank you for the help.

There is or_ expression for or conditions. Also btw there is is_ operator for comparing with NULL.
I suppose you should compare datetime column with datetime object as you do it with Flights.dept_utc. Something like:
   from sqlalchemy import or_

   another_moment = now + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)
   flight = flight.filter(
     Flights.arr_utc >= another_moment,
     Flights.dept_utc <= now,
     or_(Flights.act_in == 'None', Flights.act_in.is_(None),
     Flights.invalid==''
   )

May be I specified wrong direction of time shift, but hope it's clear how it works.

I'm actually wanting to shift the arr_utc field in the table during the query, not the now() time like this:
flight.filter(datetime.strptime(Flights.arr_utc, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') >= now, Flights.dept_utc <= now,  Flights.invalid=='')
